# Bind assertion to a module instance using generate

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level

I'm trying to bind my assertions for the module instances generated using **generate for** statment.

Below is my bind statement in my bind assert module:

```
`define NUM_BLKS 4;
genvar asrt_inst;
generate
for (asrt_inst = 0;asrt_inst < `NUM_BLKS;asrt_inst = asrt_inst+1) 
begin 
bind top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[asrt_inst].u_blk my_assert u_my_assert (
.*
);
end
endgenerate
```

Here, the RTL is under gen block of u_blk_gen[gen_var], and I'm trying to bind my assertion to each instance of the generated instance.
The path instances of the RTL, generated using the generate block are :

- top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[0].u_blk
- top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[1](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2J2r).u_blk
- top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[2].u_blk
- top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[3].u_blk

And with the bind statement, I get the below compile error:

```
bind top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[asrt_inst].u_blk my_assert u_my_assert (
                                 |
ncvlog: *E,ILLGVR (/home/user/assertion_bind.v,165|72): This genvar cannot be used in this context [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
```

Need to get rid of this issue.

Is this valid statement?

If not, is there a work around for such scenario?

[Code at EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2J2r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tools' support issue.
Contacted the vendor(cadence), which stated that this feature is supported in latest versions of the tool.

And we need to pass `-nncbind` command line option.

And this feature is supported in version **15.1** on wards and it requires additional incubation license. 
But from **15.20.008** version on wards, it does not require additional license.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to show the `generate` block in your RTL, but I think you are missing an instance name in your `bind` statement. It should be

```
bind top.u_dut.u_blk_gen[asrt_inst].instname my_assert u_my_assert (
```

If you are binding to all instances of a module, then you do not need an instance specific bind. You could do

```
bind targetname my_assert u_my_assert (
```

Comment: even with the instname, I face same compilation issue. 
Here, I'm binding to all instances, but issue is that each RTL instance is with different parameters and the my assertion has to be binded to the RTL instance with the same set of parameters which I'll be passing while binding.

Comment: Modified the query accordingly.

Comment: Code at EDA playground with same issue is [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2J2r)